# Don't have to pass in argument in addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

Why don't I have to pass in an argument when adding `playSound(e)` to `addEventListener`? How does the event automatically get passed in?

```
function playSound(e) {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  if (!audio) return; //stop the function from running
  audio.currentTime = 0; // rewinds to the start
  audio.play();
  key.classList.add("playing");
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);
```

The code works as is

Comment: it is passed by the browser automatically

Comment: The event will get passed in when it happens. Not when you install the listener.

Comment: Because you're not calling `playSound` when you pass it to `addEventListener`. You're just passing a reference of the function to `addEventListener` for it to call later when the event happens, then and only then `playSound` will be called/invoked with the event object.

Comment: ... `playSound` is the function itself. `playSound(...)` is invoking that function.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way:

```
function addEventListener(event, handler) {
  const eventObject = new Event();

  switch(event) {
    case "keydown":
      handler(eventObject);

  }
}
```

This is a simplified version obviously, but the function you pass in is called with an argument by `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

First you defined the function. In usual scenarios we will call that function some where. But in this case you want to call it when a keydown event is triggered. For that you have passed that function to keydown event as a callback. Something like below is happening behind the scenes.

```
function keydown(callback) {

 var e = getEvent(); // here it will get you the event object.
 callback(e); // here your function playSound is called.

}
```